# I have a practice problem that I need help solving

Tags: python

Write a program called Polynomial.py that lets a user enter the coefficients of a polynomial.  The program should then:

```
display the polynomial in its usual form.
(For example, if the user enters a coefficient of 4.6 for x cubed, -7.3 for x squared, 0 for x, and 9.8 for the constant, it would display:  "4.6 x^3 - 7.3 x^2 + 9.8"
Ask the user to enter a value for x, and then display the result when that value is plugged in to the polynomial function.
Allow the user to continue entering values for x until he/she decides to quit.
```

The calculation of plugging in values should be correct for the program to be considered complete.

I have not learned much from python yet which is why i am asking for help

```
poly = int(input("Enter your coefficients here"))
print(poly)
```

so far this is basically what i have learned, just basic input and output. I am not sure why i have to solve this task at hand but would appreciate some help.

Comment: What is your **specific** quetion?

Comment: Is the maximum order 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too difficult to give a student this type of assignment at the beginning of the course while the lecture only teaches you about input and output commands.

Since, it is exam period, hope the below code helps you,

```
poly = int(input("Enter degree of polynomial:"))
print(poly)
coefficients = list()
current_polynomial = ""
order = poly
while order != 0:
    coefficient = int(input("Enter coefficient for x^{0}:".format(order)))
    if coefficient != 0:
        if order < poly and order != 0:
            current_polynomial = current_polynomial + str('+ {0}x^{1}'.format(coefficient, order))
        else:
            current_polynomial = current_polynomial + str(' {0}x^{1}'.format(coefficient, order))
    print(current_polynomial)

    if order != 0 and coefficient == 0:
        order += 1

    order -= 1
```

Comment: Thank you this helped out a lot. I am not sure why we are being given such complicated programs to write. All in all, i am grateful for your help!